# Increment "PropertyInfo SetValue"

Tags: c#, propertyinfo

This is my code:

```
        Enemy ble = new Enemy();
        PropertyInfo prop = ble.GetType().GetProperty("x");
        prop.SetValue(ble,20, null);
        Console.WriteLine(prop.GetValue(ble));

class Enemy
{
    public int x { get; set; } = 20;
}
```

As you can see I have an Enemy class and I've already found out how to find that property "x" and change it's value to set value, in my example 20, but my question is, how can I increment or decrement its value by 2 for example?

Comment: Are you sure you need Reflection at all?

Comment: Yes I think I do, I want to make a little console game with dynamically created objects of unknown type at the start and since the program doesn't know all methods, properties etc of dynamic objects, I have to use reflection.

Comment: Get the value first and then increment that by 2 and set it to that new value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have already used `GetValue()` and `SetValue()`, get its value, add to it, and then again set the new value:

```
prop.SetValue(ble,(int)prop.GetValue(ble) + 2, null);
```

Comment: Yes I've already tried that but I get "Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int'"

Comment: Oh right sorry, didn't see that there. Thank you thats it!